# How can I use my jQuery code as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was running the below code. It throws the exception “variable `jQuery` is not defined”. I’m pretty sure that it’s jQuery code. Can someone help me convert my code to pure JavaScript?

```
fingerprintService = {
  hash: function(fingerprint) {
    if (fingerprint) return hashed(fingerprint)
  },
  fingerprint: function(callback) {
    var excludeScreen = gecko || msie || msedge,
      options = {
        excludes: {
          canvas: gecko,
          screenResolution: excludeScreen,
          availableScreenResolution: excludeScreen,
          enumerateDevices: !0,
          pixelRatio: !0,
          doNotTrack: !0,
          fontsFlash: !0
        }
      };
    return Fingerprint2.get(options, function(components) {
      var values = components.map(function(component) {
          return component.value
        }),
        result = Fingerprint2.x64hash128(values.join(""), 31);
      return callback.call(window, result, components)
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: You think i didn't searched, i just need the js code from above.... I spent my whole night searching the above problem but it didn't helped me...

Comment: Try importing jquery before your code lol

Comment: Since Fingerprint2 doesn't have any dependencies it's hard to see that its this code that causing the problem.

Comment: There isn't any jQuery code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery js file

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```